# Php oci8 and other extension

Tags: php, phpexcel, oci8

I use oci8 to connect to Oracle db without problem but, I get error when I try to export my result in pdf with fpdf library (hex character 47) or in xls with phpexcel library, how can I resolve it?
Thanks in advance,
Ciao
H.

Comment: Please show us your code, and tell us, what your error exactly

Comment: I get an uncouth exception hex character 47 for fpdf and for excel when I try to open it i get an error about wrong format, soon I will post an example

Comment: May be an error due to not well formatted data usual way to format it doesn't work may be i have to do it directly with oci8 but how to do it?

Comment: How to set NSL_LANG to Italian in connection? May be this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to connection page included with an empty line at the beginning of the page before opening php